# Can two admins edit the same node content at the same time from different computers?

Tags: nodes

1. Can 2 admins edit the same node content at the same time from different computers?
2. Can 2 admins edit different node contents at the same time from different computers?
3. Can 2 admins edit a Drupal site at the same time from different computers?

Comment: Simply Ans- 1 : No, 2 : Yes, 3: Yes

Comment: To all three only true answer is: **it depends on what modules you installed, how you configured them, and what exactly you mean by "admin"**. Nothing more, nothing less. Voting to close as too broad for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Drupal core, two users editing the same node concurrently would cause a conflict; the second user would get an error ("This content has been modified by another user, changes cannot be saved."). This would only happen on `node_save()`, once they have submitted the form. A more user friendly option would be to use a module like the [Content lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_lock) module which highlights an active edit of a node and locks it for others.

Any number of editors are supported on a site simultaneously; the only limitation is editing the same node (and server resources).